# how can loop through each element, evaluate conditions, then assign values to new matrix in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following matrix B:

```
B = matrix(c(2, 4, 98, 1, 5, 1), nrow=3,  ncol=2)
```

I want to loop through each element and check if it less than 3 or otherwise.
If it is less than 3, then assign the value'5', else assign the value '0' if greater than 3. My desired final result output is the following:

```
# Final result
result = matrix(c(5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5), nrow=3,  ncol=2)
```

I am a novice in R and trying with the following code, however, it is not 
working and I suspect not the most efficient. I would appreciate any feedback.

```
for i in 1:nrow(B){
  for j in 1:ncol(B){
    if (B < 3)
      result[i,j] = 5
    else
      result[i,j] = 0

  }
}
```

Comment: `ifelse(B < 3, 5, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way by multiplying the logical matrix with 5

```
(B < 3)*5
```